# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with specific column Syntax error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query which is giving me a syntax error. Can someone figure it out what's the problem?

```
$ins_cupon = mysqli_query($link, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$ruta."' INTO TABLE cupones
     IGNORE ".$lines." (@dummy, @col1)
     SET encuesta_id = '".$encuesta_id."', nom_producto = '".$nombre_producto."', cupon = @col1") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

This is the **error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(@dummy, @col1) SET encuesta_id = '555', nom_producto = 'ghjhg'
>   ,cupon = @col1' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss "LINES" after IGNORE?

```
IGNORE ".$lines." LINES
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't notice!